# grow a regression tree one split at a time

Tags: r, cart, rpart

I'm growing a regression tree with the `rpart` function in R (package of the same name). I would like to be able to choose myself the number of nodes (not the depth of the tree, but the actual number of nodes), either by growing or pruning afterwards.

The problem is that in the cptable the number of nodes jumps and skips some numbers (from 1 to 5 here). I would like, for instance a tree giving 3, 4 or 5 distinct prediction values.

```
set.seed(1)
df=data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100))
tree=rpart(data=df, y~x)
tree$cptable
####           CP nsplit rel error   xerror      xstd
#### 1 0.03357572      0 1.0000000 1.013942 0.1337594
#### 2 0.02899422      1 0.9664243 1.187690 0.1620186
#### 3 0.01488440      5 0.8504474 1.188779 0.1632158
```

And I can't find the control parameter to set this, if it is even possible (growing or pruning).
Can someone help here please?

Comment: This question has come up a number of times.  Previous answers have good reference to step-by-step generation, either enumerated in the answer or the references.  Please check them.

Comment: @EngrStudent thanks, but i still can't find the references you mention. Do you mind to post the link(s)? Thanks

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168964/building-a-regression-tree-with-r-from-scratch/168967#168967